# Duration of multiple events from a datetime column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, time-series

I have the below sample data (**multiple_sensors.csv**) from multiple motion sensors:

```
sensorid,date_time,value
303,2012-06-25 11:15:35,0
404,2012-06-25 11:15:35,0
101,2012-06-25 11:15:35,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:35,0
303,2012-06-25 11:15:36,0
404,2012-06-25 11:15:36,0
101,2012-06-25 11:15:36,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:36,1
303,2012-06-25 11:15:37,0
404,2012-06-25 11:15:37,0
101,2012-06-25 11:15:37,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:37,1
303,2012-06-25 11:15:38,0
404,2012-06-25 11:15:38,0
101,2012-06-25 11:15:38,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:38,0
303,2012-06-25 11:15:39,0
404,2012-06-25 11:15:39,1
101,2012-06-25 11:15:39,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:39,0
303,2012-06-25 11:15:40,0
404,2012-06-25 11:15:40,1
101,2012-06-25 11:15:40,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:40,0
303,2012-06-25 11:15:41,1
404,2012-06-25 11:15:41,0
101,2012-06-25 11:15:41,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:41,0
303,2012-06-25 11:15:42,1
404,2012-06-25 11:15:42,0
101,2012-06-25 11:15:42,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:42,0
303,2012-06-25 11:15:43,1
404,2012-06-25 11:15:43,0
101,2012-06-25 11:15:43,0
202,2012-06-25 11:15:43,0
303,2012-06-25 11:15:44,0
```

I need to return **id** and **duration** of each motion sensor event in order of occurrence (see [expected_output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG7Rs.png)). The **value** column determines whether a motion is triggered or not (1 - means motion triggered, 0 - means no motion) and **date_time** column indicates when the motion started or ended.

For now I managed to extract the id and duration using a single motion sensor (**single_sensor.csv**) below (see [single_sensor_output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFGwt.png)).

```
sensorid,date_time,value
202,2012-06-25 00:01:07,0
202,2012-06-25 00:01:08,1
202,2012-06-25 00:01:09,1
202,2012-06-25 00:01:10,0
202,2012-06-25 00:02:12,0
202,2012-06-25 00:02:13,1
202,2012-06-25 00:02:14,1
202,2012-06-25 00:02:15,1
202,2012-06-25 00:02:16,0
202,2012-06-25 00:03:40,0
202,2012-06-25 00:03:41,1
202,2012-06-25 00:03:42,1
202,2012-06-25 00:03:43,1
202,2012-06-25 00:03:44,0
202,2012-06-25 00:05:11,0
202,2012-06-25 00:05:12,1
202,2012-06-25 00:05:13,1
202,2012-06-25 00:05:14,0
202,2012-06-25 00:06:19,0
202,2012-06-25 00:06:20,1
202,2012-06-25 00:06:21,1
202,2012-06-25 00:06:22,0
```

For my code involving the single sensor I followed the example here ([Calculate duration between events with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767670/calculate-duration-between-events-with-pandas))

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import read_csv
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

data_time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

df = read_csv('single_sensor.csv')
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format=data_time_format)

a = (df['value'] != 1).cumsum().mask(df['value'] == 1)
df['value group'] = a.bfill()

df_final = df.groupby('value group').filter(lambda x: set(x['value']) == set([1,0]))\
           .groupby('value group')['date_time'].agg(['first','last'])\
           .rename(columns={'first':'start','last':'end'})\
           .reset_index()

df_final['id'] = df['sensorid']
df_final['duration'] = df_final['end'].values - df_final['start']
df_final['duration'] = df_final['duration'].dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
print(df_final)
```

How can I extend this to achieve my expected output using the *multiple_sensors.csv*

Comment: What is the column value? When do you consider they are start time and stop time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

Let's try this:

```
def f(df):
    a = (df['value'] != 1).cumsum().mask(df['value'] == 1)
    df['value group'] = a.bfill()

    df_final = df.groupby('value group').filter(lambda x: set(x['value']) == set([1,0]))\
           .groupby('value group')['date_time'].agg(['first','last'])\
           .rename(columns={'first':'start','last':'end'})\
           .reset_index()
    if df_final.shape[0] == 0:
        return
    df_final['id'] = df['sensorid']
    df_final['duration'] = df_final['end'].values - df_final['start']
    df_final['duration'] = df_final['duration'].dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
    return df_final

df_out = df.groupby('sensorid').apply(f).reset_index().drop(['level_1', 'value group', 'id'], axis=1)
df_out = df_out.sort_values('start')
df_out
```

Output:

```
   sensorid               start                 end  duration
0       202 2012-06-25 11:15:36 2012-06-25 11:15:38         2
1       303 2012-06-25 11:15:41 2012-06-25 11:15:44         3
2       404 2012-06-25 11:15:39 2012-06-25 11:15:41         2
```

Note: This may need a more robust test case.  But, using the previous logic in a custom function called by groupby 'sensorid'.

Comment: Brilliant thanks a lot Scott. The solution achieves what I need by grouping by sensorid, which means it finds the all durations for 202 first before moving on to 303 and finally 404. As mentioned in my question, how can I achieve the same in order of occurrence i.e. based on the 'date_time' instead of sensorid. I can share with you a much longer dataset if necessary. Thanks once again.

Comment: Precisely what I wanted. Thanks Scott.

Answer (score 0):

For a single sensor:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('single_censor.csv')
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

# Assume that your data format first value=0 ignore, start value=1 end value=0
selected_rows = df['value'] != df['value'].shift(1)
selected_rows[0] = False

df2 = df[selected_rows].copy()

df2['start'] = df2['date_time']
df2['end'] = df2['date_time'].shift(-1)
df2.drop(['date_time'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df3 = df2[df2['value'] == 1].copy()

df3['duration'] = df3['end'] - df3['start']
df3.drop('value', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output

```
    sensorid    start   end duration
1   202 2012-06-25 00:01:08 2012-06-25 00:01:10 00:00:02
5   202 2012-06-25 00:02:13 2012-06-25 00:02:16 00:00:03
10  202 2012-06-25 00:03:41 2012-06-25 00:03:44 00:00:03
15  202 2012-06-25 00:05:12 2012-06-25 00:05:14 00:00:02
19  202 2012-06-25 00:06:20 2012-06-25 00:06:22 00:00:02
```

Multiple Sensors:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('multiple_sensors.csv')
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])
df2 = df.sort_values(['sensorid', 'date_time'])

selected_rows = df2['value'] != df2['value'].shift(1)
selected_rows[0] = False

df3 = df2[selected_rows].copy()
df3['start'] = df3['date_time']
df3['end'] = df3['date_time'].shift(-1)
df3.drop(['date_time'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df4 = df3[df3['value'] == 1].copy()
df4['duration'] = df4['end'] - df4['start']
df4.drop('value', axis=1, inplace=True)
df4.sort_values('start')
```

Output

```
    sensorid               start                 end duration
7        202 2012-06-25 11:15:36 2012-06-25 11:15:38 00:00:02
17       404 2012-06-25 11:15:39 2012-06-25 11:15:41 00:00:02
24       303 2012-06-25 11:15:41 2012-06-25 11:15:44 00:00:03
```

Removing Overlapping Time:

```
data = [
    (202, pd.to_datetime('2012-06-25 00:11:47'),
     pd.to_datetime('2012-06-25 00:11:49'), 2),
    (404, pd.to_datetime('2012-06-25 00:11:48'),
     pd.to_datetime('2012-06-25 00:11:50'), 2)
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['sensor_id', 'start', 'end', 'duration'])

df['end_shift'] = df['end'].shift().fillna(pd.to_datetime('1971-01-01'))
df.loc[0, 'end_shift'] = pd.to_datetime('1971-01-01')
df[df['start'] >= df['end_shift']].drop('end_shift', axis=1)
```

Output

```
   sensor_id               start                 end  duration
0        202 2012-06-25 00:11:47 2012-06-25 00:11:49         2
```

Group durations:

```
data = [
(202, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:43'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:45'),2), 
(202, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:47'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:49'),2),
(404, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:51'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:54'),3),
(404, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:55'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:57'),2),
(202, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:58'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:01'),3),
(202, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:18'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:21'),3),
(101, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:21'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:23'),2),
(101, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:32'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:34'),2),
]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['sensor_id', 'start', 'end', 'duration'])

df['id'] = df['sensor_id'].shift(-1)
df['cumsum'] = df['duration'].cumsum()
df2 = df[df['id'] != df['sensor_id']].copy()
df2['duration2'] = df2['cumsum'] - df2['cumsum'].shift().fillna(0)
df2[['sensor_id', 'duration2']]
```

Output

```
   sensor_id  duration2
1        202        4.0
3        404        5.0
5        202        6.0
7        101        4.0
```

The requirements is not clear from the beginning. All original calculated durations are thrown away and the new durations are recalculated.  It would be better if the requirements were clear.  The solution would be shorted.

```
data = [
(202, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:43'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:45'),2), 
(202, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:47'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:49'),2),
(404, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:51'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:54'),3),
(404, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:55'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:57'),2),
(202, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:11:58'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:01'),3),
(202, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:18'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:21'),3),
(101, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:21'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:23'),2),
(101, pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:32'), pd.to_datetime('2020-06-25 00:12:34'),2),
]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['sensor_id', 'start', 'end', 'duration'])

df['id1'] = df['sensor_id'].shift(-1)
df['id2'] = df['sensor_id'].shift(1)

df2 = df[df['id1'] != df['sensor_id']].copy().reset_index()
df2['start'] = df[df['id2'] != df['sensor_id']].reset_index()['start']

df2['duration'] = df2['end'] - df2['start']
df2.drop(['id1', 'id2'], axis=1, inplace=True) 
df2
```

Output

```
   index  sensor_id               start                 end duration
0      1        202 2020-06-25 00:11:43 2020-06-25 00:11:49 00:00:06
1      3        404 2020-06-25 00:11:51 2020-06-25 00:11:57 00:00:06
2      5        202 2020-06-25 00:11:58 2020-06-25 00:12:21 00:00:23
3      7        101 2020-06-25 00:12:21 2020-06-25 00:12:34 00:00:13
```

Comment: Nice solution Pramote, works perfect. As mentioned in my post, how can I get the duration of each sensor event based on the order of occurrence i.e. 'date_time' instead of sensorid. Currently the solution first iterates through each sensorid before moving onto the next sensorid. I am happy to provide with more information if necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: df4.sort_values('start')

Comment: As a follow up to my question, my output has some overlaps as below:

`sensor_id,start,end,duration`
`202,2012-06-25 00:11:47,2012-06-25 00:11:49,2`
`404,2012-06-25 00:11:48,2012-06-25 00:11:50,2`

The end time **[2012-06-25 00:11:49]** on the first row should be less than the start time on second row **[2012-06-25 00:11:48]**

**How can I remove the overlaps?**

Comment: Do you want to adjust the time or remove them? If you want to adjust the time, which one: start time or end time?

Comment: I want to remove all overlapping cases...in this case I want to remove [2012-06-25 00:11:48] because it should not start before [2012-06-25 00:11:49] ends

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I want. I need to remove the overlap rows, in this case:
`404,2012-06-25 00:11:48,2012-06-25 00:11:50,2` 

Your solution outputs end_shift times that are different from the original end time and start time should be smaller than end_shift:

sensor_id,start,end,end_shift
`404,2012-06-25 00:11:48,2012-06-25 00:11:50.117675,2012-06-25 00:11:49`
`404,2012-06-25 00:11:51,2012-06-25 00:12:01.130899,2012-06-25 00:11:50`
`404,2012-06-25 00:12:02,2012-06-25 00:12:04.131553,2012-06-25 00:12:01`
`404,2012-06-25 00:12:18,2012-06-25 00:12:21.148316,2012-06-25 00:12:04`

Comment: Your data frame must be the output with duration, not the original data frame. Just drop column end_shift, you will get the output data frame with overlapped row removed.

Comment: Last I want duration per id interval eg

`202,2020-06-25 00:11:43,2020-06-25 00:11:45,2`
`202,2020-06-25 00:11:47,2020-06-25 00:11:49,2`
`404,2020-06-25 00:11:51,2020-06-25 00:11:54,3`
`404,2020-06-25 00:11:55,2020-06-25 00:11:57,2`
`202,2020-06-25 00:11:58,2020-06-25 00:12:01,3`
`202,2020-06-25 00:12:18,2020-06-25 00:12:21,3`
`101,2020-06-25 00:12:21,2020-06-25 00:12:23,2`
`101,2020-06-25 00:12:32,2020-06-25 00:12:34,2`

to get:
`202,4
404,5
202,6
101,4`
df.groupby(['sensor_id','start']).sum().groupby('sensor_id').sum(), gives duration per id for all rows instead of intervals

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much Pramote for the elegant solution.

Comment: I still have an issue on the start time in the final output, eg performing cumsum() on the below
`sensor_id,start,end,duration`
`202,2012-06-25 00:01:08.709140,2012-06-25 00:01:10.712482,2.0`
`202,2012-06-25 00:02:13.774037,2012-06-25 00:02:16.779430,3.0`
`202,2012-06-25 00:03:41.861496,2012-06-25 00:03:44.863977,3.0

returns:

`sensor_id,start,end,duration`
`202,2012-06-25 00:03:41.861496,2012-06-25 00:03:44.863977,8.0`

instead of:

`sensor_id,start,end,duration`
`202,2012-06-25 00:01:08.709140,2012-06-25 00:03:44.863977,8.0`

How can I get the correct start time of 00:01:08?

Comment: All start times and end times are adjusted. Durations are also recalculated.  Are you sure if these actually occur for your sensors?

Comment: Hi Pramote, sorry for the bit of confusion but the original solution is the correct one. What I mean is I want to return the original start time when the sensor gave a reading of 1 i.e., at 2012-06-25 00:01:08.709140. The duration between start and end doesnt necessarily have to be equal to be the exact [end - start]. For example I may have only a duration of 30 seconds (obtained from cumsum() of e.g., 4 seconds, 5 seconds, 3 seconds and 8 seconds) when the sensor was actually triggered (i.e., value of 1) between 08:00 to 08:05 AM.

Comment: If you want to keep start time for the first one and end time for the last one for each sensor, the duration time will be different from the original. Unless, you want to keep the original duration which is between start time and end time.  Notice, sensor 202 has a gap of two seconds  between collections. If you just record start time and end time, duration is 6 minutes.

Comment: OK I hear you! You have provided the solution already and you deserve so much recognition for your work. I just need to figure out how to tweak things. So in a layman's language if I have sequential sensor triggers for only sensor id `202` starting at `08:00` and ending at `08:20` in the following order: `08:00 - 08:06 > 6s`, `08:08 - 08:10 > 2s`, `08:12 - 08:20 > 8s`, when I cumsum() the 3 intervals I should get the output as: `sensor_id, start, end, duration: 202, 08:00, 08:20, 16s`, with 08:00 as the correct start time, instead of `sensor_id, start, end, duration: 202, 08:12, 08:20, 16s`

Comment: From my final output above I want to return a certain order of ids: where sensor id `404` is always repeated after another different sensor id. E.g, sensor_id `404` should always appear in between 2 different sensor_ids i.e., its never the case that sensor ids `202,203` should appear in that order without sensor id `404` between them. Just like from A (`202`) you have to pass through B to get to C (`203`) where B in my case is the sensor id 404. I just want to drop all cases that violate this condition. (please note this is for the final output where I have `sensor id, start, end, duration`)

Comment: I need to enhance my solution e.g., in the below, the last 2 records have a gap of 5sec instead of 1sec which affects the calculation of duration.

`sensorid,date_time,value
101,2012-06-01 10:40:35,1
101,2012-06-01 10:40:36,1
101,2012-06-01 10:40:41,0`

Current result

`sensorid,start,end,duration
101,2012-06-01 10:40:35,2012-06-01 10:40:41,00:00:05`

Desired

`sensorid,start,end,duration
101,2012-06-01 10:40:35,2012-06-01 10:40:36,00:00:01`